# how to time limit C# foreach loop to execute an iteration with max time limit

Tags: c#, time, foreach, max, limit

how to time limit C# foreach loop, every iteration should run normally and go to next iteration when the previous one take longer than 30sec.

used stopwatch, timer...but those are allowing to run iteration every 30 sec, can anyone help...

Comment: use `stopwatch` to detect running time, and use `continue` to go to the next iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or here you've got an example with Tasks.

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
   int timeout = 30000;
   var task = Task.Run(()=>SomeOperationAsync());
   await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout));
}
```

Naturally you could also enhance this one with a check if your operation finished before the 30 seconds and so something with a possible result.

Comment: Thank you Manuel for the response...it worked fine... when I tried before I missed wait for any key word, tried the same using thread. Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful for you. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to spawn a separate thread for each iteration. But thanks to anonymous delegates you can almost make it appear like code is executed locally.

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
   var threadItem = item;
   ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

   Thread workerThread = new Thread( () =>
       {
         try
            {
              // do something with threadItem in here
            }
        finally
            {
              mre.Set();
            }
       });

   workerThread.Start();
   mre.WaitOne(30000); // this will wait for up to 30 sec before proceeding to the next iteration.
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this one works but waits 30 sec before next iteration...but i want loop continues normally if in any case it shouldn't be more than 30 sec...so no need to wait every iteration....thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Just use some thread:

```
   public static void ThreadAbortDemo(int sleeptime)
    {
        int[] collection = new int[10];
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // do your stuff with item
                }
                catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
                {
                    // this thread is disposed by thread.Abort() statement
                    // do some stuff here before exit this thread
                }
            });
            thread.Start();
            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer((o) =>
           {
               try
               {
                   thread.Abort(o);
               }
               catch
               {
                   // the thread is done before Abort statement called
               }
           },new object(),sleeptime,System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
```

the code above just example, you can you another way like task or thread pool to reduce the cost of create a thread.